# show in store not working in magento system.xml

Tags: magento-1.9

I have created a section in `system->config` things are working fine.

I have defined like

```
<xyz module="abc_latest" translate="label">
     <label>my new setting</label>
     <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
     <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
     <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
</xyz>
```

but only in **store view** it is not appearing. in default and website it is showing properly.

Answer (score 1):

It also depend on your **groups** and also on **fields** nodes setting too you must enable in **groups** `<show_in_store>1</show_in_store>` and also **fields** `<show_in_store>1</show_in_store>`

```
<groups>

                <extension translate="label comment" module="sales">
                    <label>Main Setting</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <enabled translate="label">
                            <label>Enable / Disable the Extension  </label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_enabledisable</source_model>                           
                            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            <validate>required-entry</validate>
                            <comment>Enable or disable the extension</comment>
                        </enabled>
                    </fields>               
                </extension>
</group>
```